# Sublime Text 3 white boxes around lines

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

[image]

Note: Just started programming in Python using Sublime Text 3. I am not sure why I am getting the white dots/mark on every line, see image below. I would like learn the following.

1. Is it because of an error?
2. Is it because of a package or command?
3. I tried CTRL+Space,CTRL+G and CTRL+K and I still get the white marks, shall I be concerned?

Comment: 1- no 2- no 3- no :)

Comment: for coding python I suggest you `pycharm`

Comment: these white marks are options of sublime , you can disable it

Comment: A quick search of "sublime text dots" gives a really strong suspicion that the dots are showing every line that you've modified since the last save.  For what it's worth, I haven't found any actual documentation on that, though.

Comment: They kind of look like breakpoints, but Sublime does not ship with a debugger. I am interested in finding out what those are.

Comment: Did you install SublimeLinter by any chance? By default nothing in sublime is going to drop a dot in the gutter. The GitGutter plugin will add marks if your file is in source control, but not these. Based on the marks in the actual text my first guess would be SublimeLinter linting your code and finding a style issue or something.

Comment: pycharm for me so slow and stupid in set default. Sublime faster and light-weight

Comment: Hey Sublime Text and Stack Overflow users,

Quick update on those white dots you might have noticed in your code. It's a good idea to keep linting enabled – it helps you write cleaner and more standardized Python code. If you're seeing those white dots, it means PEP 8 (Python Enhancement Proposal) has flagged something in your file. To get a detailed breakdown of the PEP 8 issues by line, simply right-click on the white dot, hover over Anaconda, and select "Show Error List." 

Just discovered this tip recently, hope it proves helpful for you whom are new to dealing with linting flags.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

You probably installed Anaconda package. If so, you need to go to Preferences → Package Settings → Anaconda → Settings-User. Then paste the following code and save. Those boxes should be gone.

```
{
    "anaconda_linting": false,
}
```

Comment: This should be marked best answer as it solved the user's problem.

Comment: Solved the same issue for me.  Thanks for the correct answer.

Comment: I think you shouldn't disable the linting totally. The boxes appear because your code doesn't comply with PEP8. So instead add `{"pep8": false, "anaconda_linter_mark_style": "none",}` to `settings-user`.

Answer (score 7):

For Anaconda, consider keeping the error notifications, but making them easier on the eye.  Edit from Sublime Text > preferences > Package Settings > Anaconda > Settings - Default

> "anaconda_linter_mark_style": "none"

Here are the options:

```
/*
    If 'outline' (default), anaconda will outline error lines.
    If 'fill', anaconda will fill the lines.
    If 'solid_underline', anaconda will draw a solid underline below regions.
    If 'stippled_underline', anaconda will draw a stippled underline below regions.
    If 'squiggly_underline', anaconda will draw a squiggly underline below regions.
    If 'none', anaconda will not draw anything on error lines.
*/
```

Answer (score 4):

This is due to an incorrectly-configured SublimeLinter installation. You can read [here](https://sublimelinter.readthedocs.org/) on how to configure this quite complex plugin, along with whichever associated Python linter(s) you installed. Alternatively, you can disable the plugin entirely by selecting **`Preferences → Package Control → Package Control: Disable Package`** then typing in *`sublimelinter`* and hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

If you're interested, you're getting the errors because your code isn't [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)-compliant and contains some other errors. You need to use whitespace more:

```py
listone = [1, 2, 3]
listtwo = [1, 2, 3]
matrix_one = [listone, listtwo]
matrix_one = [row[0] for row in matrix_one] # are you sure you really want
                                            # to overwrite your original matrix?

print matrix_one # you had matrix_ones in your original code
```

I'd also **strongly** encourage you to use Python 3 if you're just beginning to learn the language. The [Stack Overflow Python community](http://sopython.com) overwhelmingly [recommends](http://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F) starting with Python 3, as does [python.org itself](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3). Version 3 is the present and future of the language, while 2 is the past. In learning 2 first, you'll pick up many bad habits that will need to be corrected when you learn 3 (which you'll need to do eventually), so it's much better to start with 3 first, then learn the differences in 2 later.

Comment: there is no sublimelinter here. any problem?

Answer (score 2):

This will solve the issue if you have anaconda package installed.

```
{
    "anaconda_linting": false,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this issue after I installed anacoda package on sublime.

so go to,

`Preferences -> Package Settings -> choose package(Anacoda) -> Settings-User`

and change it into false if it doesn't exist. otherwise copy paste into it as **@James Xingjian Zhang** suggested.

you can revert it back by changing it into true status.
[image: Anaconda Package]

```
{
    "anaconda_linting": false,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread but looking at I don't see any good answers. 
The reason linter is causing the boxes is because of poor programming style.
**Examples:** -- after the comma in a list or tuple linter is looking for a 'space' in rows 1 2 and 3.
**Example row 6:** Python is looking for the return key to be pressed to create a new line or white space at the end  of the script.
**Example row 6:** your need brackets around the printed output for python 3.

```
'listone = [1, 2, 3]'
'listtwo = [1, 2, 3]'
'matrix_one = [listone, listtwo]'
'matrix_one = [row[0] for row in matrix_one]'

'print(matrix_one)'
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to: `Preferences` -> `Package Settings` -> `SublimeLinter` -> `Settings`

Change value to `none` on `styles` -> `mark_style`

Answer (score 0):

If you click on the line with white box, you will see a lint style recommendation on the bottom of sublime text.

[image: recommendation by lint library]

White Box will go away as soon as you make the change.

[image: fixed lint]

Hope, this is helpful.